# Userform worksheet_open does not work

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Very simple VBA code.
How come my UserForm2 not opening when the workbook gets opened?

Comment: Is your Workbook_Open sub located in the ThisWorkbook code module?

Answer (score 0):

Put the Workbook_Open() sub in ThisWorkbook module, like @Rich Holton said.